# What is a good approach to preloading data?

Tags: database, web-applications, new-operator, loading

Are there best practices out there for loading data into a database, to be used with a new installation of an application? For example, for application foo to run, it needs some basic data before it can even be started. I've used a couple options in the past:

TSQL for every row that needs to be preloaded:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Master.Site WHERE Name = @SiteName)
INSERT INTO [Master].[Site] ([EnterpriseID], [Name], [LastModifiedTime], [LastModifiedUser])
VALUES (@EnterpriseId, @SiteName, GETDATE(), @LastModifiedUser)
```

Another option is a spreadsheet. Each tab represents a table, and data is entered into the spreadsheet as we realize we need it. Then, a program can read this spreadsheet and populate the DB.

There are complicating factors, including the relationships between tables. So, it's not as simple as loading tables by themselves. For example, if we create Security.Member rows, then we want to add those members to Security.Role, we need a way of maintaining that relationship.

Another factor is that not all databases will be missing this data. Some locations will already have most of the data, and others (that may be new locations around the world), will start from scratch.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: See if this SO question doesn't give you some better ideas:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503696/database-change-management-setup-for-initial-create-scripts-subsequent-migrati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not a lot of data, the bare initialization of configuration data - we typically script it with any database creation/modification.

With scripts you have a lot of control, so you can insert only missing rows, remove rows which are known to be obsolete, not override certain columns which have been customized, etc.

If it's a lot of data, then you probably want to have an external file(s) - I would avoid a spreadsheet, and use a plain text file(s) instead (BULK INSERT).  You could load this into a staging area and still use techniques like you might use in a script to ensure you don't clobber any special customization in the destination.  And because it's under script control, you've got control of the order of operations to ensure referential integrity.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a combination of the 2 approaches indicated by Cade's answer.

Step 1. Load all the needed data into temp tables (on Sybase, for example, load data for table "db1..table1" into "temp..db1_table1"). In order to be able to handle large datasets, use bulk copy mechanism (whichever one your DB server supports) without writing to transaction log.

Step 2. Run a script which as a main step will iterate over each table to be loaded, if needed create indexes on newly created temp table, compare the data in temp table to main table, and insert/update/delete differences. Then as needed the script can do auxillary tasks like the security role setup you mentioned.